# how to call asynctask manytimes for many services in android

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

I have PHP webservices and i want to call it throw `AsyncTask` ..at this stage i have no problem..my problem is that i want to make one class extends `AsyncTask` and pass to it the `uri` of the `webservices` to call it *many times in many activities* but i don't know how to do this and call the asynctask .. any help..
Thank you

this is what i have tried to do but it is not working

```
    public class GetNetworkData  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    String uri;
    private OnPostExecuteListener  mPostExecuteListener = null;
    public static interface OnPostExecuteListener
    {

                void onPostExecute(String result);

            }


    GetNetworkData(
            String Url,
            OnPostExecuteListener postExecuteListener) throws Exception {

            uri = Url;
            mPostExecuteListener = postExecuteListener;
            if (mPostExecuteListener == null)
                throw new Exception("Param cannot be null.");
        }

    @Override
    protected String  doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

        JSONObject param=null;
      String result = null;
      HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpHost httpHost = new HttpHost("192.168.3.111",80);  
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
            httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");


            try
            {
                //HttpEntity bodyEntity = new StringEntity(param.toString(), "utf8");
                //httpPost.setEntity(bodyEntity);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                if (entity != null) {
                    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                         new InputStreamReader(instream));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                        sb.append(line + "\n");


                    result = sb.toString();
                    instream.close();      
                }

                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }

        return result;
    }   

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (mPostExecuteListener != null)
         {
          try {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
                    mPostExecuteListener.onPostExecute(result);
                } catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }           
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create instances of `GetNetworkData` class wherever and whenever you need. If the `Url` and `postExecuteListener` parameters are the same across all the invocations, you could think of a wrapper class that will save these in instance variables and create the `GetNetworkData` objects on demand.

The code for using `GetNetworkData` would be:

```
String url = "http://....";
GetNetworkData.OnPostExecuteListener listener = new GetNetworkData.OnPostExecuteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("AsyncTask", "onPostExecute: " + result); 
        //Do what you want to do after the task is complete
    }
};

GetNetworkData task = new GetNetworkData(url, listener);
task.execute();
```

Comment: the url in not the same coz each url have it's own method name

Comment: in that case, you can create the instance of your `GetNetworkData` class when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

To make call do it like,

```
String url = "so and so url";
new GetNetworkData().execute(url);
```

and in your doInBackground(),

```
@Override  
protected String  doInBackground(String... params) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    urlToUse = params[0];     
}
```

Every time you Execute the AsyncTask..it will go to `doInBackgroud()` and execute the code in that..after completion of the Execution of the code..It will automatically go to `onPostExecute()` that's the LifeCycle of the AsyncTask. I think..You wont need to do anything for that..for each different call to the AsyncTask.

Comment: and what about onPostExecute how to implement it for each response